# How to use blockstream's REST api to retrieve JSON output on an address?

Tags: api, blockstream

I have a bitcoin address and I want to get the JSON format of the balance using blockstreams api service.

It's this one: https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/API.md#transaction-format

It's not clear on what I need to put in the URL. I tried:

> https://blockstream.info/address/:bc1xxxxxxx

and it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you're confused about two things. The API needs a "/api" in the URL, and the colon indicates a value to be replaced, not a literal. For example https://blockstream.info/api/address/bc1qgsmfaz22lzy08wqjspd8xtm43hal5tgz4hyac6 works.

Comment: yes that works. it doesn't say anywhere on that docs that I had to add api after the domain name. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said you can use `https://blockstream.info/api/address/bc1qgsmfaz22lzy08wqjspd8xtm43hal5tgz4hyac6` for the JSON - the doc is in reference to running a local instance - the exact endpoint is depending on deployment, the default deployment we use has nginx forward `/api/` requests to electrs without the `api` bit https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/contrib/nginx.conf.in#L32 but it depends on how people want to deploy it.

We should probably mention this in the API.md file to avoid confusion